# Google Go language plugin with AndroidStudio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, go

I am using AndroidStudio 1.2.2 and I have installed Google Go language plugin for IntelliJ Idea. I configure GOPATH and I compile and run first HelloWorld go in cmd, but i want to start learning make Android Go applications in AndroidStudio.

But when i want to run file test1.go i get error:

```
Error running test1.go: No Go Sdk defined for this project
```

I found on other forum to do this by:

```
File > Project Structure
```

but there I can only to add android/java library module and etc., (I add other java library modules, and google-play-services before).

I don't know too about Go SDK must to be:`C:\Go or C:\Go\bin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't installed already, install one of the latest version from here: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin#pre-release-builds (either alpha or nightly).
Then you can simply point the SDK to C:\Go (if that's where the Go SDK is installed).

Hope it helps.